# cómo se puede relacionar tres tablas utilizando una tabla pivot en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buen día compañeros, como puedo realizar esto con laravel, dado que las tablas son seleccionadas manualmente, mis tablas son

```
Auditoria, Segmento, Question y como tabla pivot ResultadoAuditoria
```

En cada una e intentado hacer una relación belongsToMany pero aun sigo teniendo problemas,

Estos son mis modelos

**Auditoria**

```
class Auditoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Auditorias';

    protected $primaryKey = 'IdAuditoria';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function segmentos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Segmento::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }
```

**Segmento**

```
class Segmento extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'SegmentosAuditoria';

    protected $primaryKey = 'IdSegmentoAuditoria';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function auditorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Auditoria::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }

    public function sucursals()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sucursal::class, 'sucursal_id');
    }
}
```

**Question**

```
class Question extends Model
{
    // protected $fillable = ['segmento_id', 'question', 'photo', 'comments', 'approved'];

    protected $table = 'PreguntasAuditoria';

    protected $primaryKey = 'IdPreguntaSegmentoAuditoria';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function segmentos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Segmento::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }

    public function auditorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Auditoria::class, 'ResultadoAuditoria');
    }
}
```

y mi tabla "pivot" en este caso se relacionaria con estas otras tablas por estos campos

```
IdAuditoria, IdSegmento, IdPregunta
```

Absolutamente todo va a girar sobre esta tabla pivot, e inclusive hasta modificar un capo o dos en especifico, pero eso ya es tema de otra pregunta, ya que por ahora me interesa relacionar estas 3 tablas con esta ultima pivot.

gracias por su ayuda

---

Esto es lo que he intentado hacer en tinker para ver si la relación muchos a muchos funcionaba

```
λ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.2.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $a = App\Auditoria::find(1)
=> App\Auditoria {#3198
     IdAuditoria: 1,
     NombreAuditoria: "INSPECCION SANITARIA",
   }
>>> $a->segmentos
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ResultadoAuditoria.auditoria_IdAuditoria' in 'field list' (SQL: select `SegmentosAuditoria`.*, `ResultadoAuditoria`.`auditoria_IdAuditoria` as `pivot_auditoria_IdAuditoria`, `ResultadoAuditoria`.`segmento_IdSegmentoAuditoria` as `pivot_segmento_IdSegmentoAuditoria` from `SegmentosAuditoria` inner join `ResultadoAuditoria` on `SegmentosAuditoria`.`IdSegmentoAuditoria` = `ResultadoAuditoria`.`segmento_IdSegmentoAuditoria` where `ResultadoAuditoria`.`auditoria_IdAuditoria` = 1)'
```

y como tal esa es toda la consulta que realiza pero aun así me marca error, no se si este mal definida de la relación

Comment: No termino de entender ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: No he podido hacer la relación muchos a muchos, las 3 primeras tablas a la última que vendría siendo la pivote

Comment: ¿Pero, donde está el error, al ejecutar la migración, al tratar de estructurar esta tabla pivote, al querer hacer una operación con los datos de dicha tabla?

Comment: al hacer la relacion belongsToMany y consultar los datos desde tinker

Comment: Entonces muestra el código que intentas y que no te funciona, con sus respectivos resultados.

Comment: Listo, edite para mostrar lo que hago en tinker y lo que me arroja

Comment: `ResultadoAuditoria` es la llave foránea en `segmento` ?

Comment: Es el nombre de la tabla pivot